# Override existing meta robots tag with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

Im running a Joomla 1.5 site where there are many pages being indexed by google that i dont want indexed. The built in robots field found on each article in the backend of Joomla is not working due to a 3rd party component I need to stay.

Long story short. I want to add piece of PHP (any thing that would work)  to the page that simply tells google not to index or follow. The code would need to override the default Joomla setting which is set to follow and index the page

I cant use robots.txt as there are too many Urls.

The URLS/pages were all created from a single article template, Ill add the piece of code to this article template and that should do the trick

thanks

Comment: Can you use PHP to dynamically add entries to the robots.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly you can send meta tag infos per HTTP header.
http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_meta_tag.html

So you could add a bit of PHP code before your templates if that's feasible:

```
 header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex");
```

I have no idea if this is honored in practice. The HTTP header should override the in-page meta tag however.

Comment: Am i putting it in just like that? No opening or closing php tags?

Comment: Probably with, or whatever your template thingy needs to add code.

Comment: Tried it with and without ,doesnt seem to override the default joomla meta tags

Comment: It doesn't change the tags, obviously. Please read the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 1.5 the robots meta tag is set by the metadata Commands

//dont know if you need this or if its already imported
jimport( 'joomla.document.document' );

//set default document metadata
       $this->setMetaData('robots', 'noindex, nofollow' );